# show ownership of mom

Tags: slang

My step daughter constantly while at my home says momma said.. while referring to her mother which is not me.. should she show ownership of momma while around people who do not share the same mother as her.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't appear to be about the English language or its use, but about domestic decorum.

Comment: Momma technically is a word in the English language and asking about a word's decorum is a question about its use. Regardless, younger children are not expected to actually use the language as well as someone with the maturity to know better: "You speak like a 5 year old" is effectively a compliment for anybody younger. Babies are likely to call everything momma for a while and toddlers will substitute words they know for odder ones, due to a limited vocabulary. Gently try to introduce proper words and name recognition into the vocabulary and I think the habit might slowly diminish on its own.

Answer (score 1):

Yes she can because "momma" is used by many people to refer to their own mothers. It is used by people from all around the world so it wouldn't sound unusual to hear the word(s) "(my) momma" from a lot of different children. For short, it is just a common noun.